# blender only rendering background color

Tags: rendering

I had a problem with blender only rendering the background color of my blend file.  The blend file is availble for download.  Could someone tell me what is up with it?
http://www.mediafire.com/download/ndo7g529foa6kgb/glass2.blend

Comment: objects are disabled for rendering! click on the camara icons to enable

Comment: Select all the objects in scene (A). Then use the Ctrl+Alt+H shortcut. Then hit render and everything'll work fine.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of objects are disabled for rendering:

[image]

see: [Object not visible in render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/964/object-not-visible-in-render)