# Why is part of my model not being rendered?

Tags: rendering, objects

Why is the selected object displaying in the 3D view, but not rendering?

In object mode, it shows up:
[image: object mode in 3D view]

However, it does not show up in render mode: 
[image: render view]
Why is this so and what causes it to hide in render mode?

Comment: Does the torus have a transparent material? Has it been disabled for rendering (the camera icon on the outliner)?, Is it in a different layer than the rest of the object and if so is the layer set for rendering? Are the normals for the torus faces inverted? Please add more information, or upload your blend file so someone can inpsect it and give you a clear answer

Comment: Oh whoops. But yeah, didn't know about the camera icon for disabling rendering.

Comment: Also, make sure that your object is toggled to "volume" in material viewer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a lot of reasons why this might be happening. While these may not be the reasons for why it's happening for you, it's a good place to start.

- ## Render visibility disabled in outliner

This is one of the most common reasons for something not appearing in a render.
[image]

Just make sure that this is always checked for any objects that you want to render.

- ## Blender Internal Specific Issues

When working with Blender Internal, there are some issues with materials that could be causing your object not to show up in the render.
[image]

Having those settings in your material will cause the material to be completely transparent. Having a texture effect the alpha can also cause this.

- ## Cycles Specific Issues

There are a few ways an object can be accidentally hidden from a render in cycles.

Probably the most common, is to accidentally uncheck camera from the ray visibility in the objects tab of the properties panel.

[image]

Unchecking camera will basically make the object not show up in the image (although reflections, shadows, etc. may show up and the visibility of those can be controlled using the other checkboxes)

In cycles, an object could also disappear from the render, if the material was transparent (contained a transparent shader).

- ## Layers

The last major reason why an object might disappear from a render, is layers and renderlayers. Always make sure that the object that disappeared is on one of the currently viewed layers.

For renderlayers, be sure that you have all of your scene layers selected. These are the same as your currently viewed layers, and are tied to them. If you select or deselect a layer from there, it will also be selected or deselected in the viewport.

[image]

The layer section is where you include the layers that you want used in a specific renderlayer.

[image]

The last things to check is your exclude and mask groups. The exclude group simply excludes the contents of a layer completely. No lights or anything similar from those layers will be shown.

[image]

For mask groups, just make sure that you aren't masking out any of the layers that you want visible. If you have a mask layer enabled, it will automatically cut out any pieces of it that appear in a higher Z-Depth.

[image]

Comment: Didn't know about the render visibility option.

Comment: Yup. A lot of people have this question, and it's usually that or the ray visibility options. I decided to just put a post together that would outline everything just so that we would have a good place to refer to for these types of questions.

Comment: @TARDISMaker I think you just created the best go to answer for all future "object not rendering" questions. Well done.

Comment: @David Thank you! That was my intention, so I'm glad I succeeded.

Comment: Here's another one I just did: you cranked your DOF so high the object blurs away.

Comment: Another reason can be keyframes. You move an object to place it in front of the camera, hit render... And it doesn't render because you didn't key the location in front of the camera

Comment: That's a good one to note. Thanks! I don't really think that it fit's well into the answer, but I'd like to make it visible in the comments at least, just in case one of the above solutions doesn't work.

Comment: A Mask Modifier could also cause this, if someone added it without understanding what it does. Not so likely, but something to add to the list of possibilities.

Comment: @Mentalist Thanks, I'm not going to add it to the answer, but I am UV your comment to improve visibility.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to TARDIS Maker answer.
In some cases possible that screw modifier have a different geometry in viewport and render and doesn't show in render. For avoid it set equal value in Steps and Render steps.

[image: Screw modifiers parameters]

Answer (score -3):

Flip the direction of the normals on the torus.

You can do this by selecting the object, entering Edit Mode, selecting all vertices, and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: That answer doesn't really help, can you add more details?

Comment: is it joined with the plane? and if joined than is it mirrored?