# Cloth object not rendering

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, cloth-simulation

Just as some background - it was an animated cloth object with physics, collision, and some hooks.  I "applied" all the modifiers when I liked its look, but now I'm searching for some setting that is keeping it from rendering.

Originally I was using cycles engine to apply materials, but I switched to the blender renderer and applied a new material.  Could this have been the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33787/why-is-part-of-my-model-not-being-rendered. Your object has `Restrict Rendering` option turned on. Turn it off and it will be rendered. See [wiki](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/outliner.html#toggling-object-level-restrictions) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the oultiner window the object has been disabled for rendering.

[image]

The **Eye** icon is to toggle object visibility on the 3D viewport.

The **Arrow** Icon toggles selectability.

The **Camera** Icon toggles rendering.
TO make the object renderable by enable the camera icon.

[image]