# Blender rendering only part of the objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, objects, render-layers

I have a question regarding my rendering using motion tracking.
As you can see the rendering only shows a small part of the actual 3d model (tears of steel rig).

[image: screen shot of blender showing the render, 3D view, and outliner]

Does anyone know why this occurs?

The scene can be found here

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42237

// Turning all objects at the right to render won't change anything

Comment: @David if you mark this as duplicate, could you send me a link of the duplicate?

Comment: See the box at the top of your question, that is the link. http://i.stack.imgur.com/KshNx.png

Comment: @cegaton  this doesn't change anything about the render.

Comment: @David this doesn't change anything

Comment: @cegaton I changed that, doesn't do anything :)   http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42224    <---(maybe not in the version attached)

Comment: On the right in the Outliner, you can see that there are a ton of objects that are set to not Render. So, just turn them all on and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: @LucaLange keep in mind that when you post questions, all we have to answer is the information you provide, hence all the answers pointing in a single direction. If the answers you are getting are not working for you please edit your original post and update it with information that might be useful. If you don't make it easier for others to help you you won't get good answers...

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15681/how-to-set-render-engine-in-blender

Comment: I found your issue, it's with the renderlayers. Check out my answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33787/why-is-part-of-my-model-not-being-rendered/33790#33790) and jump to the render layers bit (I'll update it with some more information, it's not very concise right now).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you created a scene in cycles and are trying to render it on blender internal.... By doing that you are trying to feed the compositor with render passes that do not exist.

[image]

Switch back to cycles or re-do your materials and compositing nodes for blender internal.

[image]

Comment: Am I not already in Cycles Render?

Comment: not on the file you uploaded!

Comment: I'm so sorry, I uploaded the wrong file :) the correct one is http://www.pasteall.org/blend/42237

Comment: Really? how is anyone supposed to help you? Please show some respect for other people's time!

Comment: I found out my mistake, it was about not selecting all layers/scenes. Thanks anyway @cegaton :)

Comment: @LucaLange nothing we could have guessed with the available info as you can see... Please be more forthcoming if you want others to help you...