# Human model and other textures won't show up on render

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I've been making animations of different accidents happening to the human model and recently I grouped them in folders. When I made another one which is already made in a new folder but still used the base file of a previous animation, the human model and other textures won't show up. The weird thing is, the shadows show up but the 3d model itself won't. I've tried almost every solution I saw in the threads here such as disabling the Render Layer, checking the toggle buttons and the Disable Restrict Layer thing- nothing works. Our deadline is on Wednesday and I'd appreciate if someone would answer ASAP. Thanks.

[image: This is the screenshot of my current work.]
And the blender file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_pEJgt9uYGSTmxVNzRYTkllZVE

Comment: See if any of the things mentioned in [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33790/2217) solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all of the materials are transparent. Change this in the material settings by disabling the transparent option.

[image]

Comment: It worked!!!!! Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!