# why are some of my objects rendering as a dark blue?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, objects

I'm making a project for my art class but for some reason 2/3 objects in my preview will not render. Does anybody know why? Its the terrain that will not render
[image: Its the terrain that will not render]

[image]

Comment: Maybe it is turned off from the render? This setting can be found in the Outliner (in the right top), next to the name of the object is a button that looks like a camera icon. Make sure it is not greyed out

Comment: none of them are grayed out so im not sure what is wrong

Comment: Are the missing objects enabled for rendering (camera icon on the outliner)?

Comment: If you can, please upload your file via this link http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: read through these posts and see if any of the proposed answers helps you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33787/why-is-part-of-my-model-not-being-rendered and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Comment: ive read that but it dosent seem to help

Comment: this is my file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3936" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3936/)

Comment: so, did any one find anything wrong in my file?

Comment: Looks like you're using nodes from another rendering engine but you're trying to render it in Cycles.  The nodes are not interchangeable.

Comment: do you know how i would edit the nodes to get them to work?

Answer (score 1):

For the dragon and other objects, you have their children objects disabled from render, as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

For the terrain, it is related to materials setup (nodes), especially try to fiddle with your alpha handling, I am not sure what are you trying to achieve there -
it would be easier to if you pack textures into the .blend and re-upload it.
I will try to correct it and then update the answer.

[image]