# Rendering ruins the scene with drastic object displacement and stretching

Tags: rendering, objects

As the screen shot shows when I render this scene the objects were completely displaced and the label stretch as compared the window render. Any ideas as to what's causing this?

[image]

Comment: Probably some modifiers were setup so to affect only on rendered image, not on viewport preview. The same with the plane - it could be hidden in the viewport, but nor in render.

Comment: If Mr. Zak's comments don't solve it for you, post the blend file.

Comment: I stripped the modifiers and it corrected the scene. Thank you.

Comment: Related - [Why is part of my model not being rendered](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33787/why-is-part-of-my-model-not-being-rendered); also - [Object not visible in render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/964/object-not-visible-in-render?rq=1) (in your case it's viceversa)