# Cycles -- Scene rendering as completely white?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera

My scene is rendering as entirely blank white. Oddly enough, in rendered viewport shading, it looks perfectly fine.

[image: Render viewport]

[image: Rendered result]

I am unsure as to what caused this.

Comment: Does this help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/964/object-not-visible-in-render I can see in the top right a few of your objects aren't set to appear in the render.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you're not previewing camera view. Press '0' on numpad keyboard and this will be your camera view.

Comment: It looks like LukeD is right, you are not previewing camera view, and your camera is probably misplaced and facing away elsewhere from your scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your Outliner, it seems that at least some of your objects are restricted from being rendered.

[image]