# Model Will Not Render

Tags: rendering, animation, mesh, camera

I am following a youtube tutorial to make a lightning animation. The youtuber repeatedly quick renders his model and is given a glowing lightning bolt against a black backdrop. However when i quick render the model all i get is a blank, grey screen. I am using the Blender render and have a camera as well as a Hemi light source in the model. I am relatively knew to Blender so apologies if it's a simple question but i desperately need help!

[image: The model before rendering]

The model before rendering

[image: The rendered model]

The rendered model

Comment: please post the link to the tutorial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object not visible in render](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/964/object-not-visible-in-render)

Comment: Can you upload the .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your render settings. My suspicion is you do not have a render layer set up.

Comment: Did you apply any materials to your scene? Did you set up a world background? Please edit your question and provide more details about what tutorial you are following.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the properties of light source is set properly and the light source is allowed to render in outliner

Comment: Ive gone over the lights properties but have found no issues and have even tried different light types to no avail

Comment: Maybe you would have restricted the light source from rendering

Comment: sorry to keep pestering you but do you know how i would rectify this issue

Comment: If this is a curve object, you'll need to make sure that you first convert it to a mesh. Make sure that the layer it is on is also allowed to render in the render layers tab.

Comment: Your problem aint solved yet?