# Visible objects in edit or object mode are invisible when rendering

Tags: rendering, mesh

I'm working on a model that has assigned materials (very simple ones, they are the default material with a color). The problem comes when i try to render it. I don't know why but most of the parts become invisible. The problem happens with cycles render and with blender render. Here is a list of things i've tried:

1. [I've checked the little camera on the Outliner view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33787/why-is-part-of-my-model-not-being-rendered).
2. I've tried to recalculate and flip normals.
3. [Clear all restricted render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/964/object-not-visible-in-render?newreg=07ad019ad0e44761b6b40397c423b517)
4. Save as a new file (i heard i had to append to a new file but im new in blender and don't know how)

This is the object on the object mode, you can see that the objects are visible (all the parts of the group are visible too)
[image: edit mode]

Here you can see the rendered image
[image: Rendered]

I don't see any difference between the objects that are seen and those that aren't but as I said, i have not much experience with Blender and i don't know where i have to look at. Most of the object has been by extruding planes or circles.

Here is the file:
[image]

Edit: I've Joined every object of the window's grid and now that part it's visible. Despite of this, the frame is invisible yet.
[image: Mistery!]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem appears to be related to the "[Duplication](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/index.html)" setting under the Object panel.

Setting it to "None" for all the objects fixes your issue. I don't know, however, if you were using the "Gruoup" setting for a purpose (unlikely so: no duplication group was selected).

[image]

Comment: Great, it did work, thank you. Why is this happening? I mean, what is the motivation of doing that change?

Comment: As far as I understand, with your settings Blender was being asked to use your object not as an object but as a placeholder for the transformations to be applied to a duplicated group of other objects. Such group, however, was not selected (see the blank line under "Group:"), thus resulting in no renderable output. However, I don't know what caused your file to be caught in that situation. Maybe as a result of duplications, parenting, or inadvertently invoked shortcuts.

Comment: or fiddling around (guilty on many occasions).  The group option sets up a [Dupligroup](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupligroup.html)  Good Catch.  @Kaostias would consider using an array modifier for the grid.