# Where did my spotlight go?

Tags: 3d-view

Is there a checklist of things to check when an object won't show in renders or 3D view?

I have one spotlight parented to an object that moves during animation. The spotlight has a node setup to shine a special emission pattern, but I don't think that's relevant.  I'm using Cycles.  It worked great the last couple weeks, but about an hour ago the lamp's output no longer shows in renders and I don't see it in the 3D view.

What could I have klutzed up this time?  'N' shows the transorm to be reasonable. I didn't accidentally move it to inside its parent object, or some other object. I didn't hide it with 'H'.  I haven't touched this spotlight for any reason since last week.

Comment: Have you check that it's in the correct render layer?

Comment: Yes, there are some good answers here that could be of help. [Visible objects in edit or object mode are invisible when rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/87570/12), note the steps (and questions) the asker went through to get more suggestions.

Comment: Solved. It was on a different layer than where I normally put lamps and objects. Turned on all the layers, and there it was :)