# My Objects, Planes, Meshes aren't rendering correctly

Tags: rendering, texturing, transparency, scene

I started using blender this year in another computer and all worked nicely until I migrated to a new PC.

I started making a room for a new scene, then I noticed it doesn't render
[image: Image of the room]

[image: This is how my render Shows]

Then I started looking on old work that used to render correctly, for example this sword:
[image: For example this blade]

[image: Now this is how the render looks in my new PC]

As you can see, the object indeed does have an appearance in my render but does not show it's body and properties.

Things/tutorials I've tried:
1-Reset blender to it's factory default

2- [https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/964/object-not-visible-in-render#:~:text=In%20object%20mode%20press%20W,objects%20visible%20in%20the%20render.&text=If%20there%20are%20objects%20that,This%20toggles%20camera%20visibility](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/964/object-not-visible-in-render#:%7E:text=In%20object%20mode%20press%20W,objects%20visible%20in%20the%20render.&text=If%20there%20are%20objects%20that,This%20toggles%20camera%20visibility)

3-https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank

Lastly
4-https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Nothing seems to solve my problem.

Comment: It looks like it could be GPU or driver related. What kind of GPU does your (new) computer have?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett
I thought of that but I didn't think it was going to be a problem
I have a AMD Radeon HD 7950
I'm using the same GPU from my old computer (which it worked before)
And installed the latest drivers from Amd Software
I've also played some games and got zero problems.

Comment: Are you using the same version of blender?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett
No, my blender just got updated 2 days ago to the latest version, just about when I changed computer, maybe I could try getting 2.8 or just 2.9

Comment: I only ask becasue 2.8+ comes with a new set of GPU requirements that weren't there in 2.79 and below. Have a look here to see if yours is supported. If not, use version 2.79 - https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/

Comment: Okay 2.79 does solve the problem, it renders correctly.
The thing is that my GPU is supported in 2.83 and I confirm that because I used to worked there (And also checked your link).
Which brings me the question, why does 2.83 & 2.91 doesn't work with my new PC?
Anyway 2.79 does work. Thanks @ChristopherBennett

Answer (score 1):

I've found my problem and solved it, at least for my specific graphics card (AMD radeon hd 7950) I had updated my drivers for the latest version (Adrenalin 2020 Edition 20.11.2, which is optional) for some reason Blender has some problems with that version, so I decided to downgrade my version to Adrenalin 2020 Edition 20.9.1 which solved every problem.
Now I can render in every Render Engine.